# How i can show a saved fav items to listViewbuilder above the api response data in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I want to save data on click the `ListView` leading button which I can do through [SharedPref](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) but i am facing a problem showing that data with API response and removing that common value and showing the Fav item on the above of all items something like this:

1. Simple List Without Any Fav Item

[image]

2. List with fav Item and see that item show at the above of the All list Item

[image]

I read that [ListViewSeprated](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-adding-separator-in-listview-c501fe568c76#:%7E:text=separated.-,ListView.,indices%20%E2%89%A5%200%20and%3C%20itemCount%20.) tutorial but I didn't know how to show the fav item in the same List Where API data showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two `ListView` namely, `PinnedItemListView` and `UnpinnedItemListView` then you just need to use both of them in a `SingleChildScrollView`. Then just remove the **fav items** from `UnpinnedItemList` and then add the same item to `PinnedItemList` and vice versa to remove the **fav item**:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                PinnedListItem(), //ListView of Fav Items
                UnpinnedListItem(), //ListView of Normal Items
              ],
            ),
          ),
```